# How to render plain html code with react-test-renderer or other alternative libs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer, snapshot-testing

`react-test-renderer`'s to JSON function returns React structure instead of plain html code.

For example:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

const Test1 = () => <span>Hello World!</span>
const Test2 = () => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'Hello World!' }} />

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li key='test1'>{JSON.stringify(renderer.create(<Test1 />).toJSON())}</li>
        <li key='test2'>{JSON.stringify(renderer.create(<Test2 />).toJSON())}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

outputs:

```json
{"type":"span","props":{},"children":["Hello World!"]}
{"type":"span","props":{"dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"Hello World!"}},"children":null}
```

So if I change my code from Test1 to Test2, the snapshot tests failed.

But actually they generate the same html structure in browser.

I wonder if there's a method can render plain html code instead of react structure. for example:

```html
<span>Hello World!</span>
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-curie-lnt6y?file=/src/App.js:0-472

Comment: This is beyond the scope of test renderer. Use (React) Testing Library.

Comment: @EstusFlask Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out with [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask)'s help.

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

render(<Test1 />).baseElement
```